# Cast as INT(11) instead of DECIMAL 11,0 in a view

Tags: mysql, view, cast

I have a view with a column defined as:

```
IFNULL(priority.id, 2) priority_id, ...
```

where `priority.id` has type `INT(11)`, however the resulting view column has type:

```
DECIMAL(11,0)
```

How do I get the resulting column to retain the `INT(11)` type?

Comment: I don't think you can use `CAST()` in DDL

Comment: You can play with `CAST(CAST(x AS BINARY(y)) AS UNSIGNED)` but that's pretty convulated, let alone elegant.

Answer (score -1):

Decimal(n,0) still treated as integer in mysql 5.0.3 and above.

Decimal (n,0) is a fixed point that did not has fractional part. 
So it is safe.

The only different int(11) with decimal(11,0) is the maximum range of number. where as the decimal has bigger range than integer

See [MySQL numeric type overview](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: The answer is obvious. Since they are treated almost equally. It's safe to just let it be. but, cast should also do it. If you insist doing it.  he he

Comment: No. That's not the point of the question. I need the view column to have type `INT(11)` and _not_ `DECIMAL(11,0)`. The view is used elsewhere by a statically typed system that will use reflection on the view and allocate a decimal-typed variable, hence the type mismatch because decimal and integer do not have the same semantics.

Comment: Ok. How about using cast(IFNULL(priority.id, 2) as int(11)) priority_id. Or using (IFNULL(priority.id, 2) + 0) priority_id

Comment: No offense, but I think you should try out your own suggestions before blindly posting them here.